# When is jQuery.ajax() complete{}?

Tags: php, httpresponse

[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is "a function to be called when the request finishes". Suppose I'm making an ajax request to ajax.php:

```
<?php

echo 'complete';

some_functions_that_echo_nothing();

?>
```

Will the complete have to wait for  some_functions_that_echo_nothing()?  If so, is there a way to make the complete{} occur right after the echo and still have the ajax.php run through till the end?

Comment: Yes, the request continues until the end of your PHP script execution.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling [`HttpResponse::send();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.httpresponse-send.php)

Comment: I don't know how that HttpResponse works. It just returns the response and keep the script going? It seems weird to me. Wouldn't that hold your apache thread. So that it would be degrading server's performance?

Comment: @eduardocereto. A server takes a HTTP request with all the data. Then you start writing to the response. `echo` is basically `HTTPResponse::write()`. When you send the HTTP response your sending out your HTML directly back to the client. You can then continue doing some processing. Once you get to the end of the file your processing should stop. All this does is send the page back earlier then normal.

Comment: @eduardocereto I assume Apache is not shit and it cleans itself. It should close, if it doesn't then that's a bug in Apache.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want to output "Complete" and let that function run in background, since it's very slow.

In that case put this function in a separate file. Let it be `proc.php` and use this instead:

```php
<?php
    echo "Complete';
    exec ("/usr/bin/php proc.php >/dev/null &");
?>
```

That will return right away and fire the `proc.php` file to run on background. Of course it won't be able to output it's return to the user, so it should mail the user when he's done, or do his own persistence.

**EDIT**: *ALWAYS* take grea care of what you put inside `exec` statements. Never put user inputs into it if you are not 100% sure you are sanitizing it *very carefully*. Even so, you really don't have a good reason to use User input into an `exec` call.

Comment: is there any reason to use this over Raynos's method.  I thought system calls were to be avoided where possible

Comment: It just feels more natural to me to end the page processing and start a new job just for that task. This is just a simple response, probably not the best solution to the problem.

Comment: A better approach would be to avoid the sys call and just append the task into a Queue, and have a job to run on cron and pull jobs from the queue.

Comment: +1.  Inserting the task into a queue is the best option, although it introduces installation/administration complexity.